# Create a class for once inside intent service

Tags: android

I am creating a intent service,and inside this intent service I am creating new class like this:

```
public class ConnectionIntent extends IntentService {
    final Connection connection=new Connection();
    public  ConnectionIntent() {
        super("ConnectionIntent");
    }
...
```

I am calling this service for multiple times.How can I create new `Connection()` class for once ? I mean if this service is calling for first create a new `Connection()` class if this service calling for secondly don't create new `Connection()` class use the old `Connection()` class.

How can I achive this ?

Comment: you cannot, the OS can kill your Service any time and recreate it with different `Connection`

Comment: But I need that connection class for each message send request.How should I resolve this ?

Comment: tried "bound [local] service" pattern?

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save it as static variable in your App class, and do something like this:

```
public class App extends Application {
   private static Connection connection;
   public Connection getConnectionInstance() {
       if (connection == null)
           connection = new Connection();
       return connection;
   }
}
```

And in your intent service do:

```
((App)getApplication()).getConnectionInstance();
```

Don't forgot to declare this class as your application class.

```
<application
    android:name="your.package.name.App"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: The field connection cannot be declared static in a non-static inner type, unless initialized with a constant expression

Comment: I said that this class should be inner class? Please check what is Application in android - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Comment: Don't call getApplication inside constructor of Service. Do it inside "onHandleIntent" method. Be sure that you add your App class inside AndroidManifest file, as I mentioned above. Check this article http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

Comment: did you know this crash ? Please I am waiting your comment.

Comment: You are trying to cast class Trackers to Bridge.

Comment: So what should I do ?

Comment: Please provide ConnectionIntent source code. Don't use screenshots, use pastbin or create gist.

Comment: So your application class is "Trackers" (according to your manifest), but you cast it to "Bridge". Stack trace quite clear says to you that you shouldn't cast Tracker to Bridge. As for me it quite clear, isn't it?

Comment: Yes I know it but what should i do for fix it ? I am not expert at android.

Comment: If you not expert and don't want to think at least a little bit then hire who are expert. ((Bridge)getApplication()).getConnectionInstance(); -> ((Trackers)getApplication()).getConnectionInstance();

Comment: Sorry,I am learning android.But normally I am getting compiler error : The method getConnectionInstance() is undefined for the type Trackers Because I don't have this method in Trackers.Should I define it in Trackers ?

Comment: Do you see any "Trackers" or Bridge in my answer? if you don't want to think just copy past my answer.

Comment: I copied your code but i used 'Bridge' instead of 'App' i mean i just changed the name of class.

Comment: Are you kidding me? Don't you see that App class in my example is used inside application tag?

Comment: I moved the getConnectionInstance method to Trackers class then it worked.Thank you for everything,please don't be angry :)